# Trigonometry equation, always ending up with root of 17

Tags: trigonometry

how would one approach to solve this equation?
$4sin^2x - ctg^2x = 0$

I transform it into a quadratic equation in which t = cosx, however i keep ending up with the wrong result and i cant seem to get around the root of 17. Please help! Thanks in advance

Comment: There will be a $\sqrt{17}$ in your result whichever way you do it. What did you expect?

Comment: From simply looking at it I can see that 45 degrees is a solution, but no matter what I do, I can't get it. This is just a part of a bigger task and when I do the rest with 45 degrees it works fine...

Comment: I don't think $\pi/4$ is a solution. $\sin^{2}(\pi/4) = 1/2$, but $\cot^{2}(\pi/4) = 1$.

Comment: you're missing the 4, check again

Comment: What am I missing? $4 \cdot 1/2 - 1 = 2 -1 = 1$...

Comment: I apologize, it was a mistake from my side, I guess the rest working was some kind of coincidence and I was just too confident. Many thanks!

Comment: No problem, happy to help! :)